# how i can crate folder with custom name in iphone using fluttter

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I want to create folder in iPhone mobile (on my phone storage) using flutter,
i complete it in androids mobile but in iOS mobile i cant do it.

when i try to get the using getApplicationSupportDirectory() its return my mac storage path not the simulator storage path

```
 if (!isTemporaryStorage) {
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
        

          var iosPath= await getApplicationSupportDirectory();

          path = File('${iosPath.path}/Majd_Eng_folder/$fileName');
        } else {
          path = File('/storage/emulated/0/Majd_Eng_folder/$fileName');
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `getApplicationSupportDirectory` to `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` for iOS. If you want to hide data's then try `getLibraryDirectory`

Note: Don't forgot to add permissions in info.plist

Comment: its still return the path to my mac
Directory: '/Users/alaabdelhadi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/41AB403B-AAE1-44DF-9FBC-71042CA7E35F/data/Containers/Data/Application/98C0D59A-6B58-4757-8D7C-9D2E2C1D8BE8/Documents'

Comment: Are you using real device or simulator.

Comment: i use simulator

Comment: did you saved any file and check in the File app ios ?

Comment: its run now after add 
 
 <key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
 <true/>

and use getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()

but the folder have also 
download_tasks.sql
GetStorage.bak
GetStorage.gs

how i can hidden them

Comment: Try getLibraryDirectory for iOS